# Does magic worn by the caster trigger the "magic detected" effect of the Detect Magic spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

Would a wizard or cleric need to remove all magic items from their own person prior to casting the *detect magic* spell to know if there were any "unknown" magic around?

In other words, does *detect magic*'s base effect simply give you a yes/no answer on whether there's any magic in the area of effect?

Comment: This seems to sort of be an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); you seem to assume that *detect magic* simply gives you a yes/no answer on whether there's any magic in the area, and then ask about something else based on that assumption. It may be better to first ask whether that assumption is true to begin with, if I am interpreting your question correctly.

Comment: That is exactly what I meant. The spell clearly states that the first effect is to be aware of magic within 30 feet of oneself, so yes, a yes or no answer, as it takes an action to see an aura around a visible item or creature

Answer (score 8):

## You do not have to remove your own magic items for *detect magic* to work

When you cast *[detect magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/detect-magic)* (PHB, 231), the spell allows you to (my emphasis):

> ...sense the presence of magic within 30 feet of you. If you sense magic in this way, you can use your action to **see a faint aura around any visible creature or object** in the area that bears magic, and you learn its school of magic, if any.

Let's say that before you cast this spell you also have some other spell ongoing on your person, that you currently have 2 known items and 1 unknown item that you don't know if it's magic or not, and that there is an unknown magic item in the room within 30 feet of you.

*Detect magic* will first tell you there is magic within 30 feet of you.

You can stop there and be happy in the confirmation you have a known spell and some known magic items, or you can can use your action to see the aura around the individual items listed above, discover new auras, and learn the item's school of magic (if any).

Comment: @V2Blast Thanks for the questions, that was some pretty awful writing. I think it's all fixed?

Comment: I meant the first part of that list: "you can can use your action to see the aura **around the individual auras listed above**, discover new auras, and learn the aura's school of magic (if any)." - The bolded part is what I was suggesting changing to "around the individual items listed above". You're seeing auras around items, not auras around auras. :P The last part of that description is also referring to the item's school of magic, not the aura's - the aura is simply a visual indicator of what bears the magic.